# ¿Como usar un spinner dentro de un mapFragment en Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, android-fragment

Estoy empezando con Kotlin ya he podido agregar Polygon y Polylines en un MapFragment, ahora lo que estoy intentando es agregar un Spinner al fragment para que dependiendo de la selleccion del Spinner sean los marcadores/polylines que se dibujen en el mapa.

Pero el problema es que no puedo inicializar el spinner me da error cuando quiero declarar e inicializarlo, en la linea "val spinner : Spinner = findViewById(R.id.spin_sector)" no reconoce el findViewById indica "Unresolved reference: findViewById"

El codigo que tengo es el siguiente:

```
package com.produccion.bottom_navigator_v2.Fragment_Map_Casos

import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.Spinner
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.*
import com.produccion.bottom_navigator_v2.R


class MapsFragment : Fragment() {


private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap
private val rojete:String = "#4DFF0000"
private val colorargb:String = "75, 0, 255, 255"



private var list_polys1: MutableList<LatLng> = mutableListOf(LatLng(0.0, 0.0))

private val callback = OnMapReadyCallback { googleMap ->
    

    val sydney = LatLng(-34.0, 151.0)
    googleMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"))
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney))

    mMap = googleMap

    mMap.uiSettings.isZoomControlsEnabled = true
    mMap.uiSettings.isCompassEnabled = true

    Sectores()
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maps, container, false)

}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    val mapFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment?
    mapFragment?.getMapAsync(callback)
       // Inicializar spinner
    val spinner : Spinner = findViewById(R.id.spin_sector)
    val numSectores = listOf("1", "2", "3", "4")
    val adaptadorSpin = ArrayAdapter(view.context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, numSectores)
    spinner.adapter = adaptadorSpin
}

private fun Sectores(){
  //carga de poligonos
  }
```

El xml es el siguiete:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/lyt_lineal_map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/const_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spin_sector"
        android:layout_width="308dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_ver"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ver"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/spin_sector" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Fragment_Map_Casos.MapsFragment" />

</LinearLayout>
```

PD: La aplicación tiene un bottom navigator y 2 fragment, uno para el mapa y el otro para reportes.

Saludos y gracias por su ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Ya he podido solucionar el problema, lo que he realizado fue dejar el spinner y el boton fuera de "FragmentContainerView" y al hacer click en el botón con el setOnClickListener verifico la posición y cargo nuevamente el fragment con navController.navigate enviándole los datos con un bundle y al cargar el fragment con un when verifico la opción indicada en el spinner, nose si sera la forma mas prolija y correcta de hacerlo pero al menos me está funcionando.

Comment: No olvides aceptar tu respuesta.